# How to change the pathname of url in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the pathname of the url, i tried but the complete url is getting modified. I need the last value of the url only needs to change.

this is what I am expecting:

Current URL : `localhost:8080/abc/index.html`
Expecting URL : `localhost:8080/abc/test.html`

THis is what I tried:

```
window.location.pathname = window.location.pathname.substring(window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

It is returning only `localhost:8080/test.html`

Comment: Could you show some more code? It's rather impossible to see where it goes wrong atm.

Comment: so you just want to change `index` to `test` ? or should it be s.th. more generic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var parts = window.location.href.split("/");
if (parts[parts.length - 1].length < 1) {
    parts = parts.splice(parts.length - 1, 1);
}
parts[parts.length - 1] = 'test.html';
parts = parts.join("/");
console.log(parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you almost have what you want, check this:

```js
var pathname = "localhost:8080/abc/index.html";

var lastItem = pathname.substring(pathname.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
alert('Last item: ' + lastItem);


var startPart = pathname.substring(0, pathname.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
alert('Start part: ' + startPart);

var newUrl = startPart + 'test.html';
alert('New url: ' + newUrl);
```